# Get date from weekview on Clicking the header

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I use unitsview and weekview in scheduler.
I need to pass `unitID(key)` and date to another function, when I click header of `classname: dhx_scale_bar`.
I tried this code:
`CODE: SELECT ALL`

```
function showTitle(a) {
    alert(a);
    debugger;
    var mode = scheduler.getState().mode;
    var myDate = scheduler.getState().date;
    alert(myDate);


    });
    if (mode == "units")
    {
        var hh= scheduler.getState().date;
        alert(hh);
        alert(mode);

    }
    else if (mode == "week" || mode=="decade") {

        var a = document.getElementById('resourcename');
        var cid = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
//here I get the unitId as i use list to filter_week.
        var n = scheduler.getState().date;
        alert(n);
// I get the same date(today's date) whenever i tried to click on any column in weekview or decade view
    }   
}
```

I attached `showTitle(a)` function in the main `dhtlmxscheduler.js` as I don't find any documentation to attach events on header. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getActionData](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_getactiondata.html) API

```
var unit = scheduler.getActionData(e).section;
```

where e - native html click event object